# How to brighten white color more without effecting the background color

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

how would I be able to increase the brightness of the white color without increasing the brightness of the grey color background? I have this lightmap texture which goes on top of the floor texture but as I try to show the white triangular white light more, the rest of the image turns more bright. I'm doing this with webgl.

I have tried:

// problem with this is that the white is too dark.

vec4 baseColor = texture2D( baseTexture, vUv) * texture2D(lightMapTexture,vUv);

and: 
    vec4 baseColor = mix(texture2D( baseTexture, vUv), texture2D(lightMapTexture,vUv), 0.5);

The effect I'm trying to get is the bottom left image where the white is more bright but does not effect the shadow grey color.

[image]

Comment: use something like screen blending or multiply blending?

Answer (score 1):

Lighting is normally done via a multiplicative blend, not an additive blend (if you illuminate a red object under blue light it should appear black - your scheme will make it look mid purple). This would also help stop your dark areas lightening up and maintain contrast (black under illumination is still black).

If you want to "over saturate" the light you can try sticking though a power function to damp down the low and midrange, and then scaling it up by a scaling factor, and then clamping the final post-lighting color between 0 and 1. If you over saturate via this scheme then you'll get clipping artefacts.